# Exclude current post in a loop using *__in (exlude without 'post__not_in')

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I would like to exclude the current post from a loop that uses `'tag__in'`argument which poses a problem as `post__not_in` and the former are mutually exclusive

> Note: you cannot combine post__in and post__not_in in the same query.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

How would I remove the current post from this loop ?

```
    <?php
    global $post;
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
    if ($tags) {
    $tag_ids = array();
    foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
    $args=array(
    'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page'=>2 // Number of related posts that will be shown.
    );
    $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    HTML HERE }}
    else { HTML HERE }}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed those are incompatible by default, but you can bypass this to use directly the `tax_query` param to your advantage.

Another tip is when you do development in WP you should turn on the `WP_DEBUG` constant on your `wp-config.php`. It flagged that `caller_get_posts` was deprecated.

```
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'tax_query'        => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'terms'    => $tag_ids,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ],
    ],
    'post__not_in'     => [ $post->ID ],
    'posts_per_page'   => 2, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
    // 'caller_get_posts' => 1 // Removing since this was deprecated.
] );
```

Let me know if that code works.

best regards,

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it doesn't seem to fetch the posts with similar tags though. The result on my page falls back to the else argument showing No Post related. (sorry for the lack of proper technical vocabulary, i'm self taught)

Comment: I added the end of the code in the original question so its clearer